# Should I implement a smart pointer type for array and support arithmetic operators?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, smart-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I heard smart pointers like std::shared_ptr, std::unique_ptr (and in addition array classes like std::array boost::shared_array) but those pointers don't support arithmetic operations.

I want a smart pointer type only for array that acts like normal pointers, in other words, it can have ++p, p++,  p--, p+n, n+p, *p, p[n], p-> operators etc.

so I wrote a class ArrayPtr:

```
template <typename T>
class ArrayPtr final
{
public:
    typedef size_t size_type;

    ArrayPtr() noexcept;
    ArrayPtr(nullptr_t) noexcept;
    ArrayPtr(T p[], size_type size);
    ArrayPtr(const ArrayPtr &p);
    ~ArrayPtr();
    ArrayPtr & operator = (const ArrayPtr &p);
    ArrayPtr & operator += (size_type offset);
    ArrayPtr & operator -= (size_type offset);

    T & operator * () const noexcept;       //  dereference *p
    T & operator [] (size_type index) const;//  dereference p[index]
    T * operator -> () const noexcept;  //  dereference p->

    ArrayPtr operator + (size_type offset) const;
    ArrayPtr operator - (size_type offset) const;

    ArrayPtr & operator ++ ();  //  prefix  ++p
    ArrayPtr operator ++ (int); //  suffix  p++

    ArrayPtr & operator -- ();  //  prefix  --p
    ArrayPtr operator -- (int); //  suffix  p--

    inline T * get() const noexcept;
    inline T * getFirst() const noexcept;
    inline T * getLast() const noexcept;
    inline size_type getPos() const noexcept;
    inline size_type getSize() const noexcept;

private:
    void addPtr(T p[], size_type size);
    void removePtr(T p[]);
private:
    T *m_ptr;
    size_type m_pos;
    size_type m_size;
    struct PtrCounter
    {
        T *ptr;
        size_type size;
        size_type count;
    };
    static vector<PtrCounter> sm_ptrCounters;
};
```

It act like shared_ptr, but to make a dynamic array you should do: `ArrayPtr p(new int[8], 8)`
When accessing array elements you can use `p[3] = 10;` or `*(p+4) = 20;`

And you can also have `p++` and `p += 5`

When you try to give an index out of the array's bounds, it throw an OutOfBound exception.

I use static member sm_ptrCounters to record the number of pointers that points to the same array.

I can't tell the advantage of doing this, I'm just a nerd that want things to be consistent. And I'd like to know why shouldn't I do this (since no c++ library provide this feature).

Any suggestion is welcome :)

Comment: That's what iterators are for (act like a pointer on a standard container or array)! You don't need to implement this yourself.

Comment: Also, this helper class is not so *smart*, because you'd have to clean memory by yourself.

Comment: The `inline` specifier is not needed, member functions are inline by default.

Comment: @SChepurin I delete the array in destructor when sm_ptrCounter.count == 0

Comment: @Manu343726 Really ? I remember member functions defined in the class body is implicitly inline

Comment: @Linlix -"I delete the array in destructor" - So, you should've mentioned this. C++ tries to get rid of pointer's usage because it is not safe and error prone to handle language construction. Thus, it creates *smart pointers* leaving the raw pointers (and anything that wraps it) to speed hungry implementations and code maintenance.